# How to avoid the move constructor in debug macros?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move

I'm trying to write a debugging macro / template that outputs the name of the function followed by the return value and then returns that value. I've come up with 4 makros: `RETURN` for fundamental types, `RETURN_P` for pointers in std wrapper (uniqe_ptr, shared_ptr, optional), `RETURN_B` for booleans and `RETURN_A` for things I can only show the address of.

To test the macros I've written a `Resource` class that is movable but not copyable and has a "private" constructor. I use the private access argument to prevent anybody from calling the constructor while preserving the ability to use forwarding functions like `std::make_unique`. This is a test object so it provides factories for all the types I have encountered so far. For each type there is a factory that creates the type as part of the makro invokation and a factory that first creates a temporary variable and then invokes the makro with it.

Last the `main()` function creates a lot of `Resource` objects testing all the makros, including int and bool fundamental types.

Now here are my problems:

1. With NDEBUG defined the `alloc_opt2` and `create2` methods invoke the move constructor of Resource. Can that be avoided in some way?
2. When NDEBUG is not defined the `alloc_opt` and `create` methods invoke the move constructor of Resource as well. I realy want to get at least those moves elided away so the behaviour is the same with and without NDEBUG.

Is there something that can be done?

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <experimental/optional>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdio.h>

class Resource {
    struct access { };
public:
    static Resource * alloc_ptr();
    static Resource * alloc_ptr2();
    static std::unique_ptr<Resource> alloc_uniqe();
    static std::unique_ptr<Resource> alloc_uniqe2();
    static std::shared_ptr<Resource> alloc_shared();
    static std::shared_ptr<Resource> alloc_shared2();
    static std::experimental::optional<Resource> alloc_opt();
    static std::experimental::optional<Resource> alloc_opt2();
    static Resource create();
    static Resource create2();
    Resource(access);
    ~Resource();
    Resource(Resource &&other);
    operator bool() const;
private:
    Resource(const Resource &) = delete;
    Resource & operator =(const Resource &) = delete;
    bool valid;
};

#define NDEBUG

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define RETURN(format, arg) return arg;
#define RETURN_P(arg) return arg;
#define RETURN_B(arg) return arg;
#define RETURN_A(arg) return arg;
#else

template <class T>
T debug(const char *format, const char *name, T && t) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[<T>] ");
    fprintf(stderr, format, name, t);
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

template <class T>
T debug_p(const char *format, const char *name, T && t) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[ptr<T>] ");
    fprintf(stderr, format, name, t ? &*t : nullptr);
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

bool debug_b(const char *format, const char *name, bool t) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[bool] ");
    fprintf(stderr, format, name, t ? "true" : "false");
    return t;
}

template <class T>
T debug_a(const char *format, const char *name, T && t) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[&<T>] ");
    fprintf(stderr, format, name, &t);
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

#define RETURN(format, arg) return debug("%s : " format "\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, arg);
#define RETURN_P(arg) return debug_p("%s = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, arg);
#define RETURN_B(arg) return debug_b("%s = %s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, arg);
#define RETURN_A(arg) return debug_a("%s = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, arg);

#endif

Resource * Resource::alloc_ptr() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    RETURN_P(new Resource(access{}));
}

Resource * Resource::alloc_ptr2() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    Resource * r = new Resource(access{});
    RETURN_P(r);
}

std::unique_ptr<Resource> Resource::alloc_uniqe() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    RETURN_P(std::make_unique<Resource>(access{}));
}

std::unique_ptr<Resource> Resource::alloc_uniqe2() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> r = std::make_unique<Resource>(access{});
    RETURN_P(std::move(r));
}

std::shared_ptr<Resource> Resource::alloc_shared() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    RETURN_P(std::make_shared<Resource>(access{}));
}

std::shared_ptr<Resource> Resource::alloc_shared2() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    std::shared_ptr<Resource>  r = std::make_shared<Resource>(access{});
    RETURN_P(r);
}

std::experimental::optional<Resource> Resource::alloc_opt() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    RETURN_P(std::experimental::optional<Resource>(std::experimental::in_place, access{}));
}

std::experimental::optional<Resource> Resource::alloc_opt2() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    std::experimental::optional<Resource>  r = std::experimental::optional<Resource>(std::experimental::in_place, access{});
    RETURN_P(std::move(r));
}

Resource Resource::create() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    RETURN_A(Resource(access{}));
}

Resource Resource::create2() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    Resource r = Resource(access{});
    RETURN_A(std::move(r));
}

Resource::Resource(access) : valid(true) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

Resource::~Resource() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s [%s]\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
            valid ? "valid" : "invalid");
    valid = false;
}

Resource::Resource(Resource &&other) : valid(other.valid) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    assert(other.valid);
    other.valid = false;
}

Resource::operator bool() const {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    RETURN_B(valid);
}

int test_int() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    RETURN("%d", 1);
}

int main() {
    fprintf(stderr, "### test test_int()\n");
    {
    int i = test_int();
    fprintf(stderr, "### test test_int() created\n");
    if (i) { }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test test_int() done\n\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_ptr()\n");
    {
    Resource * r1 = Resource::alloc_ptr();
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_ptr() allocated\n");
    delete r1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_ptr() done\n\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_ptr2()\n");
    {
    Resource * r1 = Resource::alloc_ptr2();
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_ptr2() allocated\n");
    delete r1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_ptr2() done\n\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_unique()\n");
    {
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> r2 = Resource::alloc_uniqe();

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_uniqe() allocated\n");
    if (r2) { }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_uniqe() done\n\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_unique2()\n");
    {
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> r2 = Resource::alloc_uniqe2();

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_uniqe2() allocated\n");
    if (r2) { }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_uniqe2() done\n\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_shared()\n");
    {
    std::shared_ptr<Resource> r3 = Resource::alloc_shared();
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_shared() allocated\n");
    if (r3) { }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_shared() done\n\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_shared2()\n");
    {
    std::shared_ptr<Resource> r3 = Resource::alloc_shared2();
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_shared2() allocated\n");
    if (r3) { }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_shared2() done\n\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_opt()\n");
    {
    std::experimental::optional<Resource> r4 = Resource::alloc_opt();
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_opt() allocated\n");
    if (r4) { }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_opt() done\n\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_opt2()\n");
    {
    std::experimental::optional<Resource> r4 = Resource::alloc_opt2();
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_opt2() allocated\n");
    if (r4) { }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::alloc_opt2() done\n\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::create()\n");
    {
    Resource r5(Resource::create());
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::create() created\n");
    if (r5) { }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::create() done\n\n");

    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::create2()\n");
    {
    Resource r5(Resource::create2());
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::create2() created\n");
    if (r5) { }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "### test Resource::create2() done\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In non-NDEBUG mode, the move constructions in `create`, `create2`, `alloc_opt` and `alloc_opt2` may not be removed (*elided* as the standard calls it), as this elision is forbidden if you return a function parameter. I tried hard but failed to find a way to debug return values transparently, safe to use and without moving. Combining NRVO with dumping the value before returning seems to be the best idea - but this means, as I said *first* dump it, *then* return it, instead of passing it *through* a debug dumping function.

So you have something like

```
    Resource r(access{});
    DUMP_RESOURCE(r);  // disappears if NDEBUG
    return r;
}
```

Make sure you don't

- put the return statement inside a block (like the `do { } while(0)` trick)
- return any expression more complicated than the name of a variable (like `std::move(r)` or `(DUMP(r), r)`

(edit 4: removed idea here that proved to not work well, and explain what does work instead.)

There also is no compiler-independent way to get rid of the moves in NDEBUG mode. The C++ standard explains that return-by-value results in a move- or copy-construction, which *may* be elided to optimize the program, except for one special case:

```
return {access()};
```

In this case only, direct construction of the returned value is guaranteed.

I would expect a good compiler to remove the move-constructions if optimizations are enabled in all cases if NDEBUG is defined. In case of `create` this is called the return-value-optimization (RVO), while in `create2`, this is called the named-return-value-optimization (NRVO).

It is not considered good style to `std::move` local variables in return statements, and furthermore `std::move` inhibits NRVO in `create2` on g++ 4.9. I do understand that you need the std::move if you pass that object through the debug functions, though; but here you can follow Jonathan Wakely's advice of putting that std::move into the debug macro, which seems a good idea to me, too.

(edit 3: I tested the statement in the last paragraph)

---

A workaround to get some object created by a function into the realm of the caller without moving is that instead of returning it, you `emplace` it into a caller provided std::experimental::optional, which is passed-in in disengaged state.

```
void Resource::workaround(std::experimental::optional<Resource> &output)
{
    output.emplace(access{});
#ifndef NDEBUG
    debug_print(*output);
#endif
}

// call site:
int main()
{
    std::experimental::optional<Resource> result;
    Resource::workaround(result);
    // work with "*result" now
}
```

Just as with return-by-value, result is managed on the stack of main, but you are guaranteed to get no move constructions.

(Edit 2: completely reworked workaround added in edit 1)

Comment: _"I do understand that you need the std::move if you pass that object through the debug functions, though."_ The `std::move` could be put in the macro though, so `RETURN_A(arg);` expands to `return arg;` or `return debug_a("%s = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, std::move(arg));`

Comment: "A workaround to get a value from a function into a location the caller manages would be to pass an std::experimental::optional by non-const reference or pointer into the function and emplace-ing the return value into it. You can pass it by reference to a debug-printing function afterwards, if needed."<br>
This is to debug whatever return value some function has. So how to return something isn't up to me. It has to work on anything.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That moves all the move constructors squarely on the debug case. One could call that progress but it makes the difference between debug and non-debug mode greater. :(

Comment: @MichaelKracher I'm using g++-4.9 -O2, which usualy optimizes quite well.

Comment: `#define RETURN_A(arg) do { auto x = arg; debug_a("%s = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, x); return arg; } while(0)` You can't evaluate `arg` twice. Did you mean `return x;`?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I hope my edit cleared up what I meant with that workaround.

Comment: Yes, I meant "return x;". I am sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. With NDEBUG defined the alloc_opt2 and create2 methods invoke the move constructor of Resource. Can that be avoided in some way?

Yes, that's easy, just stop writing `RETURN_X(std::move(r))` and say `RETURN_X(arg)` instead, where the macro calls `std::move` instead:

```
#define RETURN_X return debug_x("%s = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, std::move(arg));
```

Now when NDEBUG is defined the return statements are just `return arg;` so you get move elision.

When NDEBUG is not defined you still move the return value into the debug functions as before.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new answere as this gets too long for comments:

> You could try to work around this along the lines of

```
#define RETURN_A(arg) do { auto t = arg; \
    debug_a("%s = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, &t); \
    return t; } while(0)
```

> because in this case you are returning a local variable where copies may be elided.
>   (Edited: renamed x to t, return t and output &t to match previous `RETURN_A`)

This results in the following error:

```
debug.cc: In static member function 'static Resource Resource::create2()':
debug.cc:129:14: error: use of deleted function 'Resource::Resource(const Resource&)'
     RETURN_A(r);
              ^
debug.cc:73:37: note: in definition of macro 'RETURN_A'
 #define RETURN_A(arg) do { auto t = arg; fprintf(stderr, "%s = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, &t); return t; } while(0)
                                     ^
debug.cc:25:5: note: declared here
     Resource(const Resource &) = delete;
     ^
```

Neither `std::move(t)` nor `std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)` solve that.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not see your extra answer yesterday. This approach does not work out with g++-4.9, I will edit my answer accordingly. Additionally, I stumbled over something that is likely a bug with NRVO while experimenting with it. Taking the address of a local variable and having it NRVO'ed does not play nice together.

Comment: I retract anything I claimed about a bug in gcc. It was a bug between chair and keyboard. It is too late to edit that part out of the previous comment. On the other hand, I would not be disturbed at all if this answer and my two comments are just deleted.

Comment: Could taking the address of the variable to print it be the cause for extra moves? As in prevent the NRVO from being legal.

Comment: No. Taking the address does not prevent NRVO, I tested it while writing the last edit for my answer. &t does actually address of the space provided by the caller, although it syntactically is a member of the callee.